# How can I duplicate my firework rockets in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In creative mode, I can create a firework rocket, and set it off as many times as I want by right-clicking somewhere. However, I want to set up a red-stone circuit with dispensers to set off many fireworks at once with a nice spread, and a pre-programmed pattern.

In order to do this, I need the ability to duplicate rockets. Creating them manually takes so much time, because I have to go one at a time to collect gunpowder, paper, dyes, etc.

Is there a way I can duplicate my completed rockets in Creative mode? This would save lots of time. What would you suggest?

I am running my world using the minecraft_server.jar provided by minecraft.net. I can install additional plugins there as needed, unless of course I can already do this with Creative-mode only.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Assuming you are in Creative Mode (as stated in your question), you can use the **Pick Block** control (defaults to middle mouse button) on the Firework Rocket item and you will get an extra 64 of it.

[image: Pick block to clone Firework Rockets]

This doesn't only apply to Firework Rockets. You can clone any items with this key. You will get the maximum stackable number of that item (64 on most items, 16 on some others and 1 on armors/tools/etc).

Any properties (e.g. damage levels, fireworks, enchantments, potion effects, written books, etc.) will be cloned.

Comment: this does not seem to work in bedrock edition

Answer (score 6):

As of 1.5, you can use the Pick Block key (defaults to wheel/middle-mouse button) to get a stack of any item you are pointing at with your mouse cursor. Craft a single firework, put it in your inventory, then middle-click it. You'll now be holding a full stack of fireworks rockets matching the one you crafted.

---

In Minecraft versions before 1.5, you can exploit the behaviour of [item frames](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Item_Frame) to duplicate items like fireworks.

1. **Enable cheats.** Either make your world with the cheats option on, be an op in multiplayer, or in Singleplayer you can "Open to LAN" and enable the cheats option there. (This gives you access to the `/gamemode` command, which will be necessary.)
2. **Switch to creative mode.** Use `/gamemode c`.
3. **Make one firework.**
4. **Place a lot of item frames on a wall.** One for every firework rocket that you eventually want to have is ideal, but you can make do with less by simply repeating this whole process.
5. **Fill the frames with rockets.** Still in creative mode, right-click every item frame with your rocket. Each will now have a copy of the rocket. (Note that if you break a frame now, the frame and rocket just disappear. Not helpful!)
6. **Switch to Survival mode.** Use `/gamemode s`.
7. **Collect the rockets.** Break all the item frames and you'll be showered with copies of your rocket.

Answer (score 0):

the NBTEdit mod has a duplicate command. I am not totally sure what it is, because I have only heard about it from a friend. It should give you a stack of 64 of whatever is in your hand.

Answer (score 0):

If you are playing on your server and willing to install plugins, you can use the Bukkit plugin Essentials. This will allow you to use `/more` while selecting an item to get a full stack of it.

Answer (score 0):

Click the item with your middle button on your mouse and it gets duplicated