# Minecraft Creative - Click Duplicate Items

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I watched this video by Etho:
[Etho's Mini Farm](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHmKsHrtHYw)

And at 45s he picks a whole stack of items out of a chest, just by clicking on a single item.
How does he do that?

Comment: Same as what I've answered in another question. http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/110415/38938

Answer (score 11, accepted):

same [source](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Controls) as [@rayfloyd](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/112511/13414)'s answer

> Hovering over an item in an inventory and **clicking with the mouse
> wheel** when in creative gives the maximum stack of that item.

Comment: Or whatever the "Pick Block" key has been set to.

Answer (score 1):

Left-Clicking whilst holding down left shift in survival mode also does this. I use this as I have a laptop. Laptop=touchpad=no mouse wheel.

Comment: That just moves a full or partial stack to or from a container. It doesn't create a full stack from one item.

Comment: Imagine if it did and all of us didn't know there was a secret right under our keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

You can also hover over the item and press shift click. This is also used for moving things from your first line to inventory and to easily put armor on

Answer (score 0):

i just simply do shift+left-click and then go into creative inventory and do the same thing with the same item and it will fill the stack

Answer (score 0):

Hover over an item, Shift-Click, then left click

Comment: This answer doesn't seem to be any different from some of the existing answers.